# Update errors Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, updates

I have a dual boot win10/Ubuntu system. I had been out of the ubuntu a couple of days. After logging in this a.m. I ran sudo apt-get update. Then sudo apt-get upgrade and there was an error code relating to teamviewer.

E: Failed to fetch http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/pool/teamviewer_14.0.8346_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 2600:9000:2004:cc00:1c:3aaa:b100:93a1 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I tried typing --fix-missing and just fix-missing but konsole said commands not found. I tried going to the http link it listed and google says not found.

Pretty new to linux so please advise.

Comment: In my case this same error occurs only if I am using organization proxy and proxy is blocking the teamviewer. Try by connecting open to internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list` is probably incorrect.

Edit the file and make sure it says this:

`deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main`

**Update #1:**

Probably the easiest way to edit this is to start `Synaptic`, enter your password, go to the Settings menu, choose Repositories, Other Software tab, find the teamviewer entry, and edit it there.

[image]

Comment: How do I edit the file? in any word processor?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to start `Synaptic`, enter your password, go to the Settings menu, choose Repositories, Other Software tab, find the teamviewer entry, and edit it there.

Answer (score 9):

Remove broken teamviwer source list file and try to update.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list
```

It won't impact on your Teamviewer which is installed. 
In future you can install latest teamviewer by downloading debian package from its official site. Above file will be generated automatically when you install it.